# How can I keep an absolute div from disappearing when the parent collapse is collapsed? (Material-UI)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `Collapse` element with a button that is absolutely positioned *outside* of the collapse. Basically, the collapse sits off to the right of the screen, with the button inside the screen ( so it hangs off the left of the collapse div).

So when you click it it toggles the collapse. However, when the collapse is set to collapsed, it hides the button. I've tried overflow, I've tried visibility. I've tried !important and forcing things. Z-index, etc. I'm sure there's a setting I don't know about.

I can *see* the div in the chrome inspector when it's collapsed, but it's invisible. What prop would I use on the button or the collapse to let the absolutely-positioned element show?

[image: invisible element]

[image: Some CSS props on the button element under collapse]

Comment: did you check if there is a `display: none`?

Comment: Can you paste the css rules that are attached to that button? Could be opacity, display, and a myriad of other things.

Comment: I overrode all of those on parent all the way down. There's no real way to show the local browser here, but I listed some of the things I tried. I don't think I tried opacity though. I wish there was a way to make it easier, and I'm certainly open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I pasted an image with all of the properties I think could do it. I'm not sure how to display it on here, but I hope this helps!